# Studying mathematics concretely, axiomatically & philosophically

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I see mathematics as structures made up of numbers & shapes and actions done with them, like additions-multiplications-exponentiations, or divisions in pieces, translations, rotations, or some other changes of shape.

I'm exploring whether something substantial can be said in general, e.g. about “addition”, “multiplication”, the “distributive law” and “exponentiation”,
in a *broad philosophical outlook*,

(*for example, one could argue that adding is simple amassing, while multiplying is structuring the collected pieces in geometrical forms*),

that would provide some clues to a unified understanding of pre-19th century algebra, geometry, calculus & complex variables, and motivate their further study, possibly some books on general axiomatic theories (groups, sets, topology, categories…) with historical accounts and many concrete examples.

Comment: "unified understanding of pre-19th century algebra" ? Do you mean modern historical studies or pre-19th century treatises ?

Comment: For a pre-modern point of view (but it is end-19th), see e.g. [Alfred North Whitehead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_North_Whitehead), [A Treatise on Universal Algebra: With Applications](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonuniv00goog) (1898).

Comment: There are both research journals and books dedicated to the history of math. I just found an interesting journal article on the historical development on the concept on "open set" for example. It sounds like you might be interested in the history of set theory possibly.

Comment: Maths is just applied set theory. 'Simple amassing' makes no sense mathematically, addition is just a function which in turn is just a set.

Comment: @Someguy: i understand this view, and it is exactly what i want to avoid.